# Scope of OraOLEDB.Oracle provider and OledbConnection with c# application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

My c# 4.0 .netframework application needs to support connectivity with oracle databases starting from 9i version to 12c . I am planning to use OraOledb.Oracle provider and use system.data.oledb connection to establish connection with oracle. The application would be limited to performing select queries from views & Tables. My aim to have a single exe to handle the requirement with different oracle databases. I was having some doubts on certain things and  wanted to clear them before going about it

1. Will my c# application have some limitations if I go with oledbconnection and oraOledb providers ?
2. Will it support all versions of oracle client and databases installed in a client location ?
3. Will my application required to be compiled in specific platform say x86, x64 or Any cpu to be supported across both 32bit & 64 bit windows 7 PCs?

Well if there is something more I should be thinking of, please help me with them .

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think so. OraOledb.Oracle provider should be able to connect to any Oracle Database from 9i to 12c.
2. Well, see answer 1 and 3
3. It depends mainly on the architecture of installed Oracle Client. If your client PC has x86 (32 bit) Oracle Client installed then you must compile to `x86`. In case of an 64 bit Oracle Client you must compile to `x64`. `AnyCPU` means on a 64-Bit Windows a 64 bit Oracle client must be installed. Also advise your customer to install Oracle OleDB provider, it is not part of the Oracle Instant client, you have to enable the feature in OUI (Oracle Universal Installer) or install it manually.

You see, there are many potential problems. Consider to use the [ODP.NET Managed Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html), it makes your job much easier. Simply provide a copy of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` in your application directory and that's it.

It also does not matter if you compile to `x86` or `x64` or `AnyCPU`.

Comment: i got the point number 3. Does that mean i must always have 2 exe's for support different OS Platforms. Is it anyway possible to manage the situation with a single exe ?

Comment: You must provide two different exe's. But it is not the matter to support different OS Platforms, it is to support different Oracle client which are installed. You can install 32 bit Oracle Client on Windows 64 bit without any problem. In this case your customer has to use your `x86` application.

Comment: if i use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client dll, do i need to install this in the client machine as well

Comment: There is nothing to install, just provide a simple copy of the dll file